# Why is the ideal generated by the image of $P$ a prime ideal of $K \otimes_{k_0} k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Reference: David Mumford, *The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes*, Section II.4, Theorem 1.

Let $k_0$ be a field, $k$ its algebraic closure, $R$ a $k_0$-algebra.  If it helps, assume $R$ is finitely generated.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R \otimes_{k_0} k$, and let $P_0 = P \cap R$.  Let $K = R_{P_0}/P_0R_{P_0}$ be the quotient field of $R/P_0$.

The homomorphism $R \rightarrow K$ induces a homomorphism $R \otimes_{k_0} k \rightarrow K \otimes_{k_0} k$.  The book I'm reading claims that (i) the ideal generated by the image of $P$ in $K \otimes_{k_0} k$ is a prime ideal $\mathscr P$ of $K \otimes_{k_0} k$, and that (ii) the contraction of $\mathscr P$ is again $P$.  I don't see why either of these things must be true.

I think this is because $K \otimes_{k_0} k$ is supposed to be a localization of $R \otimes_{k_0} k$ at some multiplicatively closed set inside $R \otimes_{k_0} k$, but I am having trouble seeing this.

Comment: Don't you want to say that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: It is implicit from the context of the question.  Algebraic geometry is foremost concerned with commutative rings with identity.